# Not able to get all the links properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am new to python, and have little confusion over the code.

In the below code i am trying to get all the links of one table, this is giving me all the links, the code is this:

```
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
i=0
url = "http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/bill_expired.asp"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name="frm")
br["AcctId"] = '8428995632'
br.submit()
for link in br.links(url_regex="ID="):
    print link
```

now when i am adding one more parameter to get print of the same page, i am not getting all the links which were printed previously and data which i want to print for all the links page, below is the code, these the extra line i have added

```
    billurl = "http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/"+link.url
    billdata = br.open(billurl)
    html = billdata.read()
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html)
    print soup1('font')[0].text[11:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open your new links with new mechanize instance:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

i=0
url = "http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/bill_expired.asp"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br1 = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name="frm")
br["AcctId"] = '8428995632'
br.submit()
for link in br.links(url_regex="ID="):
    print link
    billurl = "http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/"+link.url
    billdata = br1.open(billurl)
    html = billdata.read()
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html)
    print soup1('font')[0].text[11:]
```

Although I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range` on `print soup1('font')[0].text[11:]`. Check if your scrapping the webpage correctly (when I open the link that your script outputs, webpage is empty)

---

Output:

```
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842891990247', text='08-21-2013', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842891990247')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842892230704', text='07-22-2013', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842892230704')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842890786086', text='06-20-2013', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842890786086')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842892747030', text='05-22-2013', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842892747030')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842899532902', text='04-22-2013', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842899532902')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842899515711', text='03-21-2013', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842899515711')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842899587533', text='03-05-2013', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842899587533')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842899585097', text='01-29-2013', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842899585097')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842899536357', text='12-20-2012', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842899536357')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842899543531', text='11-26-2012', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842899543531')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842899524946', text='10-25-2012', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842899524946')])
Link(base_url='http://www.miamidade.gov/water/bill_app/BillHistoryLookup.Asp', url='BillDetail.asp?ID=842899578848', text='09-21-2012', tag='a', attrs=[('href', 'BillDetail.asp?ID=842899578848')])
```

Comment: And you can see data when you open links in web browser?

Comment: i think its the problem with the last 2 lines of the beautiful soup part, if we remove that and try to print the html it prints properly

Comment: Then your question is answered. All you need to do now, is to check that you are selecting correct element.

Comment: i am selecting the correct element too. its happening for the first 2 links and not for rest of the links.

Comment: i am still not getting all the links data. for loop is just getting me 2 links.

Comment: And the code which has been provided u, gives me that error as that new instance doesn't have the source page code of that link.

Comment: You sure you know how to copy and paste? I executed script one more time. I added output for you

Comment: can u tell me which code have u used? and also if u see, my first piece of code, that gives this output but when i integrate the second piece f code, that doesn't work . Please check once. I dont need the link, but i need that data from the page when that link is hit.

Comment: I used the exact code that I posted. Just copy and execute it. Without any changes! I can't open the links from your script, it just  outputs `Last Visited » Back to Top Page Last Edited: Thu Feb 9, 2012 12:00:39 PM. `. That's all.

Comment: Can u tell me which code have u pasted?and yes if u directly open that link it wont open, u need to log in with the account number.

Comment: i have used your code only, i still get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#234>", line 7, in <module>
    print soup1('font')[0].text[11:]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: and br1 will not have that font tag, as you have not logged in with that instance, and even that instance page will not have that details. please check

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looping over a list that's based on the internal data members of the "br" object. But inside the loop, you're modifying the "br" object. So the loop breaks.

Try copying the links into another list, and looping over that list.

Comment: What do u mean ? i cant understand it.can u help me with the code plz.

Comment: We both gave the same answer. Or use code from my anwser, or first create variable, assign all links to that variable. And then use that variable in for loop (not br.links).